# string with only letters - didnt work

Tags: c, if-statement

I need to code term that tells me if the "matrix name" is valid or invalid.

The name should consist only letters, big or small.
But the problem is, it has condition in "if" which always tells me that the `name is invalid`, Although it is not.

Please help me to figure out what I did wrong.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {    
    int i; 
    char mtx1[10];

    gets_s(mtx1_name, sizeof(mtx1_name));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(mtx1_name); i++)

        if ((mtx1_name[i]<'a' || mtx1_name[i]>'z') && (mtx1_name[i]<'A' || mtx1_name[i]>'Z') && mtx1_name[i]!='\0')
        {
            printf_s("Eroor: '%s' - illegal variable name! \n", mtx1_name);
            i = sizeof(mtx1_name);
        }
}
```

Link for the code image can be found

[image]

Comment: `i = sizeof(mtx1_name);` You can just use `break;`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Also, `for (i = 0; i < sizeof(mtx1_name); i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < strlen(mtx1_name); i++)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: or better: `for (i = 0; mtx1_name[i]; i++)`

Comment: The root cause analysis would suggest that what you're doing wrong is not using a debugger, or even debugging prints. If you'd write out each inspected character one by one before the if, with for example `printf("Checking character %d: code %d, %c\n", i, (int)mtx1_name[i], mtx1_name[i])` you'd be one step closer to discovering the problem.

Comment: BTW, except for VLA, the value of `sizeof` is determined at the compilation stage, so you can't use it to calculate the length of a C string.

Comment: Please only paste code, that actually compiles. There is no definition of `mtx1_name` but only an unused variable `mtx1`

Comment: if you include the header file: `ctype.h`  then you can use `if( isalpha(x) )` to verify the characters.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems:

- The prototype for `main` is not `void main()`
- The array name should be `mtx1_name`, not `mtx1`.
- Test the return value of `gets_s()`
- Stop the loop t the end of the C String in the array, otherwise you access an uninitialized portion of the array, which has undefined behavior.
- Preferably check for letters with the functions from `<ctype.h>`
- If you insist on explicit comparisons, which works for ASCII, use a more readable set of comparisons. Don't worry about performance, the compiler will likely generate the same code, but the code will be easier to understand by the next reader

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char mtx1_name[100];

    if (gets_s(mtx1_name, sizeof mtx1_name)) {
        for (int i = 0; mtx1_name[i]; i++) {
            if (!((mtx1_name[i] >= 'a' && mtx1_name[i] <= 'z') ||
                  (mtx1_name[i] >= 'A' && mtx1_name[i] <= 'Z'))) {
                printf_s("Error: '%s' - illegal variable name! \n", mtx1_name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more portable version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char mtx1_name[100];

    if (gets_s(mtx1_name, sizeof mtx1_name)) {
        for (int i = 0; mtx1_name[i]; i++) {
            if (!isalpha((unsigned char)mtx1_name[i])) {
                printf_s("Error: '%s' - illegal variable name!\n", mtx1_name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mtx1_name` is undefined.